# R connection to Bloomberg

Tags: r, bloomberg

I would like to know if there is  a way to connect R to Bloomberg in order to get real market data (the RBloomberg package does not work on the latest R version :

```
    install.packages("RBloomberg")
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Documents and Settings/b001akh/My Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RBloomberg’ is not available (for R version 2.15.0)
```

)

Otherwise, I know that there are other packages to get market quotes with R such as quantmod but I would like to use Bloomberg to avoid the 15-20 min delay.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some good [news](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/RBloomberg-package-rename-td4630766.html) for you:

> The package formerly known as RBloomberg has been renamed Rbbg

so try

```
install.packages("Rbbg", repos = "http://r.findata.org")
```

Comment: Ok Thanks! I guess you have experimented that package? Does it work well?

Comment: I haven't, I just found that post now. But it seems that there shouldn't be any big changes and it should work as `RBloomberg`

Comment: just to remind that Rbbg is **NOT** supported on Mac OS... (quantmod FTW!)

Comment: Ok. It would be interesting if someone could make a little feedback about that package. The package description is very brief.

Comment: The package works fine. I use it all the time and it has all the features from the API.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, allow me to mention that Whit, John and I released a new package [Rblpapi](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rblpapi.html) to CRAN which you can install directly via

```
  install.packages("Rblpapi")
```

It does not depends on Java, and works on Windows, OS X and Linux.